# Find all files with an undefined GID (A group without an entry in /etc/group)

Tags: linux, configuration-management

On several of our CentOS 5 systems, the /etc/group file was munged by an automated script.

As a result, there are some files on the system which have an undefined GID-- the GID is not defined in `/etc/group`. For example, the following file is owned by GID 103, when it should be owned by the group 'mysql'.

```
# ls -ld /var/lib/mysql/mysql/user.frm 
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql 103 10330 Apr  1 02:47 /var/lib/mysql/mysql/user.frm
```

Is there a way for me to find ALL files on this system which are owned by undefined groups?

I know I can do something like this to find all files owned by GID 103:

```
find / -gid 103
```

However, I want to find ALL files which are owned by an undefined group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doesn't your version of find have the `-nogroup` option?

Here is a perl one-liner:

```
perl -MFile::Find -e 'find({ wanted => sub { getgrgid((stat(_))[5]) or \
  print ((stat(_))[5], " $File::Find::name\n") }, follow => 1 }, "/")'
```

Comment: Despite the other accepted answer, this one really is the -right- one.  Using the `-nogroup` flag with find will return all files with which the GID doesn't map to an actual group.  Exactly what the poster was looking for.

Comment: Wow, I wonder why I have never noticed this option before.

Comment: You win! I had no idea that option existed. I even scanned the manpage and missed this option.

Answer (score 4):

you may try a quick and dirty solution like:

```
find .  -ls | gawk '$6 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ {print}'
```

it's definitely not a beauty, but should work.

Comment: I like that better than what I was coming up with :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have `-gid` but not `-nogroup` you may be able to use this or something like it:

```
gids=($(cut -d: -f3 /etc/group | sed 's/.*/! -gid & /'))
find /dir/to/start ${gids[@]} -ls
```